# Inequality About $f(t)=\int_{0}^t \sqrt{\cos(x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

During my projet, I encountered the following function defined for all $\displaystyle t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ by :
$$f(t)=\int_{0}^t \sqrt{\cos(x)} dx$$

and I need to prove the inequality below :

$$\forall x,y >0\ \ \ \  x+y\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{f(x+y)^2}{\sin(x+y)}\leq \frac{f(x)^2}{\sin(x)}+\frac{f(y)^2}{\sin(y)}  $$

I don't really know if the inequality is true or not , what I know is that I want it to be true, so I can go forward in my work.

**Questions**

1. Is there a closed form for the function $\displaystyle f$?.
2. Can we prove the inequality above.

For the first question for $\displaystyle t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $\displaystyle f(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})^2$ (see [walframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5BSqrt%5Bcos%5Bt%5D%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2CPi%2F2%7D%5D&lk=4&num=1)) and for the other values of $\displaystyle t$, mathematica made use of elliptic integral and I don't know their properties very well, Using the values for some elements I conjectured that :
$$ f(t)=2 E(\frac{t}{2}|2) $$
$\displaystyle E(x,m)$ is the elliptic integral with the second kind with the parameter $\displaystyle k=m^2$

Is this equality true? can this help me solve the second question?

**Update :** using the definition of the elliptic integral I proved that:
$$ f(t)=2 E(\frac{t}{2}|2) $$ 
hence the first question is solved, but I still can't use the proprieties of the eleptic integrals to prove the inequality, I think that there is no hope that the inequality is true.

Any help/comment will be greatly appreciated,Thank you.

Comment: This may be pedantic, but do you mean $f(t) = \int_0^t \sqrt{\cos(x)} \, d x$?

Comment: yes , you're right I will correct it, thanks;

Comment: Take $g(x) = \frac{f^2(x)}{\sin(x)}$ then you need to show $g(x) + g(y) \geq g(x+y)$. It suffices to show that $g'(x) \leq 1$.

Comment: @Winther thanks,your comment was very helpful in fact I proved that $g'(x)\leq 1$ how I can prove your statement : $g'(x)\leq 1 \Rightarrow g(x)+g(y)\geq g(x+y)$

Comment: I might have been to quick with that comment. On second thought I think you need to show that $g''(x) \leq 0$ (so that $g'$ is decreasing). Then $g(x+y) - g(x) = \int_x^{x+y} g'(t) dt$ and $\int_x^{x+y} g'(t) dt = \int_0^{y} g'(t+x) dt  \leq \int_0^{y} g'(t) dt =  g(y)$ gives the result.

Comment: @Winther , this one is diffuclt I must prove that $$f(x)\geq \frac{2\sqrt{\cos(x)}\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}\cos(x)+\sin(x)^2}$$

Comment: Are you sure? $g''(x)\leq 0$ is true for all $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ (seen from just plotting it), but that inequality is not true. Just take $x=0$ to get $0\geq 2$.

Comment: I don't know if the inequality is true or not (like I said in the question). you are right , unfortunately, the inequality is not true, then I have to find the values $(x,y)$ for which it holds. thanks

Comment: I'm talking about the inequality you posted above. The inequality in your question does hold.

Comment: In fact, I made a mistake :

Comment: A lot of mistaks, this is the expression of $g""(x)$: $$ g''(x)=-\frac{cos(x)^2+1}{\sqrt{cos(x)}sin(x)^2}(f(x)-\frac{\sqrt{cos(x)}cos(x)sin(x)}{cos(x)^2+1})(1-\frac{\sqrt{cos(x)}f(x)}{sin(x)})$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20745/discussion-between-elaqqad-and-winther).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(0) = 0$, $g'(x) \geq 0$ and $g''(x)\leq 0$ then

$$g(x+y) - g(x) = \int_x^{x+y} g'(t)dt = \int_0^{y} g'(t+x)dt \leq \int_0^{y} g'(t)dt  = g(y)$$

giving us

$$g(x+y) \leq g(x) + g(y)$$

If we define

$$g(x) = \frac{f^2(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}g(x)  = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = 0$ and to prove the inequality we need to show that $g'(x)\geq 0$ and $g''(x)\leq 0$.

Take $w =  \frac{f(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}}{\sin(x)}$ to find

$$g'(x) = 1 -\left(1 - w\right)^2$$

$$g''(x) =  -2\left(1 - w\right)\cot(x)\left(\left(\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2}+1\right)w-1\right)$$

We now need to show $1 \geq w\geq \frac{1}{\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2}+1} = \frac{2\cos^2(t)}{1 + \cos^2(t)}$. The first inequality, $w\leq 1$, follows from

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - f(x)\right) = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^{3/2}(x)} \geq 0$$

and the second inequality follows form

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x) - \frac{2\cos^{3/2}(x)\sin(x)}{(1 + \cos^2(x))}\right) = \frac{4\sqrt{\cos(x)}\sin^2(x)}{(1+\cos^2(x))^2} \geq 0$$

Comment: How did you conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$? Confused there

Comment: @jameselmore I should have added more details. We have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{\cos(x)}$ by L'Hopitals rule. This gives $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \cdot \frac{f^2(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \cdot \cos(x)$

Comment: i don't think that we need $g(0)=0$

Comment: @Elaqqad For the argument here we do otherwise we get $g(x+y) - g(x) \leq g(y) - g(0)$ (since $\int_0^y g'(t) dt = g(y)-g(0)$) so we get $g(x+y) \leq g(x) + g(y) - g(0)$ instead of $g(x+y) \leq g(x) + g(y)$.